If Chazal say a Torah scholar should not accept gifts, then why is it a mitzvah to give tzedakah?
"Peninim On the Torah" by Rabbi A.L. Scheinbaum states that humans reflect HaShem, BH, in the way that we are self-sufficient. The book states that G-d needs nothing and gives everything, and it states that people should be self-sufficient and give to those in need to mirror G-d. The book goes on to further state that one should not give what he accepted from others; it is bad to give from a source that originates from outside of ourselves. Thus, it is not ideal to accept gifts from others.
1.) How are humans self-sufficient? In my opinion, humans are particularly dependent on their surroundings for survival. In modern times, most of us are dependent on grocery stores, employers, builders, clothing stores, etc. We need food, water, healthy relationships, teachers, money, etc.
2.) If everyone were to stop accepting gifts, no one would be able to fulfill the mitzvah of giving charity because there would be no one to give charity to. Is this situation preferable to its opposite: accepting gifts and being able to give charity?
3.) Is the lesson that we should only give what we earned (e.g. through a job or providing goods/services) instead of giving from handouts we receive? If this is true, then why are we obligated to tithe gifts of money?
4.) What are examples of physical things that people could give which come "from inside ourselves"?
5.) Isn't giving someone the opportunity to do chesed or give tzedakah a merit?

I think the intention is "only accept gifts as a last resort" not "never ever ever accept a gift ever"
